# Glide no muestra mi imagen en mi ImgView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy presentando problemas con Glide sigo todos los pasos verifique mis dependencias, los permisos, entre otras cosas y no logro hacer que muestra la imagen.

Estoy usando Android Studio con Kotlin.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

````
//El IMGVIEW

              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/imgCover"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="@dimen/card_img_cover_height"
                  android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                  android:background="@color/fondo2"
                  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                  android:visibility="visible"
                  />
  
  // El llamado a Glide
  
   Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://palaciodeljuguete.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/unicornios-palaciodeljuguete.jpg")
            .into(binding.content.imgCover)
            
            
  //Las dependencias
  
  
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'



//Los permisos

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> ```
````

Comment: android:layout_width="0dp" ¿?

Comment: Lo estoy dimensionando desde otro lado, ya intente con un proyecto nuevo y tampoco funciona

Comment: Este llamado Glide.with(this) lo tienes en una Activity, el layout que carga esta Activity tiene el ImageView imgCover ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia el atributo de tu ImageView de:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

a el valor:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```